# Dependency 'me.sargunvohra.lib:pokekotlin:2.3.0' not found

Tags: java, api, maven, kotlin, pokeapi

I'm trying to use the PokeAPI for a Java Project. It should work, however, when I try to add the dependancy to my pom.xml, it doesn't recognise it. I have the files downloaded from the github, and have the following code in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>me.sargunvohra.lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>pokekotlin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbKcc.png)

But I keep getting this error:

> Could not find artifact me.sargunvohra.lib:pokekotlin:pom:2.3.0 in
> central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Does anyone know how to properly add this dependency? The code below does not work when I try to use it.

```
PokeApi pokedex = new PokeApiClient ();
                PokemonSpecies pokemon = pokedex.getPokemonSpecies (1);
                System.out.println(pokemon);
```

P.S. I have tried to invalidate cache and restart, that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

The artifact is located at Spring Plugins repository (https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/) so you need to add it to your pom.xml as follows:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-plugins-release</id>
        <name>Spring Plugins</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```